# Implementing an interface's `internal set` property on an implementation

Tags: c#, oop

I have a (public) interface, `IAuditLogConfig` which has a property with a public getter and an internal setter:

```
public interface IAuditLogConfig
{
    int ElementTypeId { get; internal set; }
    
    // ...and other methods
}
```

Implementations of this interface are instantiated via a factory which is in the same library and which will set the `ElementTypeId` property.

```
public IAuditLogConfig Create(int elementTypeId)
{
    var key = ...;
    var auditLogConfig = _auditLogConfigFactory.ComponentExists(key)
                             ? _auditLogConfigFactory.CreateComponent(key)
                             : new GenericAuditLogConfig();

    auditLogConfig.ElementTypeId = elementTypeId;
    
    return auditLogConfig;
}
```

But how do I declare this property on the implementation classes?

Here's an example of the problem I have when declaring the setter on the `GenericAuditLogConfig` class which is in the same library:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to create any class, implementing `IAuditLogConfig` interface?

Comment: Yes, the `GenericAuditLogConfig` class which is referenced in the `Create` factory method. This is where I have the problem which I'm asking about.

Comment: Are the implementing types in the same assembly (or using IVTA)? If not: you can't. You've basically made an interface that can't be implemented externally (similar to creating an abstract base type with only internal constructors). So... don't do that?

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing declaration of this setter on an internal class.

Comment: @awj you could try using an explicit interface implementation, but frankly: this internal setter is just a bad idea, and nothing will change that

Comment: Did you try making class public?

Comment: Looking at the language spec at the moment, it would appear that the compiler violates the spirit (and indeed the letter, at least of version 6) of the spec if it allows that `internal` on the property setter in the interface declaration.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't want the class to be public, I want it instantiated only from the factory.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think I was trying to be too clever by fastening down as much as possible, but it looks like I've just made a rod for my own back. Ok, it's back to `{ get; set; }` with that property.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate **internal** interface with a setter for this property. Because the interface is internal, the interface cannot be used outside the assembly.

**Explicitly** implement IHasElementTypeIdSettable on each type returned from the factory and you should be good to go!

```
    internal interface IHasElementTypeIdSettable
    {
        // since the class is internal already, you can choose 
        // to leave out the internal keyword on the setter.
        int ElementTypeId { get; internal set; }
    }

    public interface IAuditLogConfig
    {
        int ElementTypeId { get; }
    }

    public class GenericAuditLogConfig : IHasElementTypeIdSettable, IAuditLogConfig
    {
        private int _elementTypeId;

        // exposes a public getter.
        public int ElementTypeId { get { return _elementTypeId; } }

        // explicit implementation of IHasElementTypeIdSettable results in a
        // public getter and setter when cast to the internal interface: IHasElementTypeIdSettable
        // this results in the getter and the setter also being internal
        int IHasElementTypeIdSettable.ElementTypeId
        {
            get { return _elementTypeId; }
            set { _elementTypeId = value; }
        }
    }

    public IAuditLogConfig Create(int elementTypeId)
    {
        var key = ...;
        var auditLogConfig = _auditLogConfigFactory.ComponentExists(key)
                                 ? _auditLogConfigFactory.CreateComponent(key)
                                 : new GenericAuditLogConfig();

        ((IHasElementTypeIdSettable)auditLogConfig).ElementTypeId = elementTypeId;

        return auditLogConfig;
    }
```

Comment: `GenericAuditLogConfig` is not `IAuditLog` in the code here. How the `return auditLogConfig;` will work?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for pointing this out, I indeed forgot to add IAuditLog to GenericAuditLogConfig. I edited my answer and made it more clear.